# Need Help Applying a Custom Chrome json Theme

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-theme

I need some help, I had sometime ago made a custom .json theme for use with chrome.
Anyways, my problem is this thing about the "manifest_version 2" thing. My current code below has always worked when I would go into extensions and click "Load unpacked extension" and it would perfectly apply my theme, but until today its no longer valid and I can't apply my theme to Chrome. The only thing I can think of is i'm guessing chrome updated?

side note: I'm a little lost when it comes to editing or knowing the vocabulary of json files or how this coding works. So if anyone can, can you please tell me almost in laymans/specifically as possible in what I have to change to my previously working code below so that it may work with this manifest_version 2? Basically what do I have to do to apply my theme back on chrome so that it may work.

Thank you!

Here is the previously working .json code

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"name": "02 Lancer Dark World",
"theme": {
"images" : {
  "theme_frame" : "images/frame.png",
  "theme_toolbar" : "images/toolbar.png",
  "theme_ntp_background" : "images/background.png",
  "theme_tab_background" : "images/tab.png"},
"colors" : {
    "ntp_link": [25,110,172], 
"ntp_text": [49,143,255], 
"ntp_section_link": [89,4,255], 
"ntp_section_text": [25 , 110 , 172],
"ntp_background": [10 , 17 , 27], 
"frame": [10 , 17 , 27], 
"toolbar": [10 , 17 , 27], 
"tab_text": [93,205,255], 
"tab_background_text": [82 , 127 , 204], 
"bookmark_text": [49,143,255],
"button_background": [5, 23, 37]
},
"tints" : {
            "buttons" : [0.6, 0.9, 0.4],
            "frame_inactive": [0.5, 0.6, 0.1], 
            "frame_incognito_inactive": [0.5, 0.6, 0.1] 
},
"properties" : {
    "ntp_background_alignment" : "top",
"ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top:

{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",

Done